# Swift failable initializer calling ExpressibleByStringLiteral initializer

Tags: swift, initialization

This is the strangest problem I've had in swift and its driving me crazy trying to figure it out.

I have a struct called `Algorithm` that conforms to `LosslessStringConvertible`, so it has a failable init. Just to test it, it always returns nil:

```
init?(_ description: String) {
    return nil
}
```

`Algorithm` also conforms to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`, using the previous init:

```
extension Algorithm: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(value)!
    }
}
```

But when I create an instance of `Algorithm` from the first init, I can see in Xcode that its not an optional

```
let a = Algorithm("test")
a // a: Algorithm
```

And then I run the above code, it crashes on the line `self.init(value)!`, from the `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` init.

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening. Im calling one initializer, and a completely different one is being run.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Reproduced. The interesting part is that `Algorithm.init("test")` or `Algorithm(String("test"))` will fix the problem. I guess it's something to do how `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` is implemented by the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue has been already reported in [SR-10259](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10259) and it seems this is expected behavior coming from [Literal initialization via coercion (SE-0213)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0213-literal-init-via-coercion.md)

Possible workarounds:

```
Algorithm.init("test") // don't coerce, call initializer
```

```
Algorithm(String("test")) // convert literal to a `String` first
```